# php call static function of class dynamically(function name is unknown)

Tags: php

Here is my Class:

```
class ProcessUploadedExcel {
 public static function test1($a,$b)
    {
        dd('hi');
    }
 public static function test2($a,$b)
    {
        dd('hi');
    }

}
```

in another file I want to call one of the functions. So I included the file:

```
use App\Library\ProcessUploadedExcel;
```

the function is stored in a variable and when I use [call_user_func_array](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php) I get an error:

```
ProcessUploadedExcel::test1(1,2);//works fine.

$func_name = 'test1';
call_user_func_array("ProcessUploadedExcel::" . $func_name, [1,2]);//gets error
```

error:

> call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback,
>   class 'ProcessUploadedExcel' not found

Comment: *in another file* Is the file containing the class `ProcessUploadedExcel` included/required in the calling class ?

Comment: The error tells you that the class isn't found which as @Cid has said the class isn't included, as that code works fine when both the class and query are included within the same file.

Comment: Please extract and provide a [mcve]. There's too much guessing as to what you're doing exactly.

Comment: include it with `require_once 'path/to/class.php';`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[call_user_func_array](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php) ignores the [use](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php) and you have to provide the full path:

```
$func_name = 'test1';
call_user_func_array("App\Library\ProcessUploadedExcel::" . $func_name, [1,2]);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this:

```
class ProcessUploadedExcel {
 public static function test1($a,$b)
    {
        //dd('hi');
        var_dump($a,$b);
    }
 public static function test2($a,$b)
    {
        dd('hi');
    }
}

$func_name = 'test1';
ProcessUploadedExcel::$func_name(1,2);
```

Output:

```
int(1) int(2)
```

or if you want to use call_user_func_array()

```
call_user_func_array([ProcessUploadedExcel::class,$func_name],[1,2]);
```

Both solutions work properly with use and namespaces.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this way:

```
class ProcessUploadedExcel {
    public static function test1($a,$b)
    {
        echo ('hi');
    }
    public static function test2($a,$b)
    {
        echo ('hi');
    }

}

$func_name = 'test1';
call_user_func_array([ ProcessUploadedExcel::class, $func_name ] , [1,2]);
```

Comment: This is the best solution for working with namespaces. ProcessUploadedExcel::class is a constant which takes use into account and has here the content 'App\Library\ProcessUploadedExcel'.

Answer (score 0):

First misconception is that you "included the file: `use App\Library\ProcessUploadedExcel;`". No, you just told PHP that whenever it encounters `ProcessUploadedExcel`, you actually mean `App\Library\ProcessUploadedExcel`. This doesn't include anything. Including something is a different mechanism using `require` or `require_once`. Actually including the file is done by the autoloader in most projects.

Now, you pass a string to `call_user_func_array()`. PHP doesn't look inside that string, so it can't tell that you mean something different than what you write there. Inside the called function, where the string is used, the above `use ...` is not effective, so the function fails since it can't find the according callback.

Remedies:

- You could provide the fully qualified name `"App\\Library\\ProcessUploadedExcel::test1"` as parameter.
- You could make PHP look up the fully qualified name for you using `ProcessUploadedExcel::class . "::test1"`.

I'm not sure that either of these works though, but check the documentation which way to specify a callback exist. Maybe you need to specify class and function separately like `[ProcessUploadedExcel::class, "test1"]`.